# My folder is not opened in XAMPP localhost

Tags: php, api, xampp, vimeo

Guys i am frustrated now, I just installed XAMPP yesterday. And I created a folder named "MyProgram" and there is one PHP file inside and basically its just a "Hello World" program. It works fine in the apache localhost.

And now when I created another new folder "MyAPI", I am trying to build another PHP thing with Vimeo API. But this time, no matter how many times I tried, I cant open my "MyAPI" folder on the localhost anymore. Usually when we open in the localhost, there will be a menu for us to choose what file to be opened, but im not sure why this is not working in this case. These are the error message:

**Warning: require(vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\index.php on line 9**

**Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='D:\XAMPP\php\PEAR') in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\index.php on line 9**

**And FYI, this my folder:**
[image]

**And this is how I installed my composer:**
[image]

Comment: you already run `composer install` in your terminal?

Comment: Yes Sir, i have run that in the CMD

Comment: I have re-edit my question, this  is how I install my composer. Is that correct?

Comment: what he printed? why composer did not installed your project dependencies in vendor directory?

Comment: you need to run composer inside your project directory

Comment: hmm sorry Sir I didnt quite get it

Comment: you are running your terminal in `C:\Users\user` directory, please go to your app directory and then run `composer install` again

Comment: I posted an answer with the commands you need to run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220393/discussion-between-andre-walker-and-mlsiew).

Comment: but i have one question, why is it when I open in XAMPP, it will just open my index.php? Rather than showing a menu and show other file as well?

Comment: this is the goal of `index.*` files. they are globally interpret as text file that you wanna execute in many server. because they have to start in some file. you can rename and than you xampp will list all files.

Comment: Alright thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi my genius friend. I just faced another problem... Appreciate if you can share some thoughts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63574280/how-to-call-a-vimeo-api-in-php?noredirect=1#comment112432931_63574280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install your project dependencies first.

1. Open your terminal
2. Navigate to your project directory:
   `cd D:\XAMPP\htdocs\MyAPI\`
3. Run `composer install`

Comment: is it normal if it takes very long to run the "Composer Install" in my project directory? Coz its showing this message in my cmd for many minutes already "Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
"

Comment: Yes. It's normal. Especially at the first time

Comment: Its still running haha

Comment: Glad to help you 

Answer (score 2):

try to run :

```
composer install
composer update --no-scripts
```

If you get the same error also when you run them

Just run this command first

```
composer dump-autoload
```

**also make sure you run these commands inside the project folder**